# Ignore prompt while user already logged in

Tags: openid-connect

The available values for prompt parameter of the Authentication Request are as follows:

- none: This will never display login UI and will succeed if the user is already logged in.
- login: This will always display Login UI to reauthenticate the user. Even if already logged in.
- consent: This will always display the Consent UI. Even if previously authorized.
- select_account: ...

None of them serve the following flows:

- If the user is logged in, return success. Else, display Login UI.
- If the user is logged in and previously authorized the client app, return success.

Answer (score 1):

I think the `prompt` parameter is exactly for the opposite to what you would like to have - it's there to require or force some behavior instead of the default one. For example with `none`, you assume the user has a valid session at the OAuth2 server and you access the `/auth` endpoint using a hidden `iframe`, so you want it to fail instead of presenting a login screen if there is no session.

The second missing `prompt` parameter value you described is the default behavior (no `prompt` parameter present). The first one could get around the consent screen, so I think it would violate the OAuth2 principles.

Comment: Additionally, Many Authorization Providers will return  login_required, or interaction_required if the use id not logged in or has not provided consent for when making an Authorization Request when using prompt=none.

Comment: @ján-halaša Could you please refer to a place in some standard specification that talks about the behavior when prompt is omitted? Just to build the argument on a reference instead of having argument from silence.

Comment: @ján-halaša About the first missing prompt parameter value that I'm assuming: it will not get around the consent screen. If no consent is required then it is valid to return "user authentication successful" even without any authorization to the client (ex. the client didn't ask for any claims). OR if the consent is required for the requested claims, it should return consent_required.

Comment: I don't know about any spec that would discuss the OAuth2 server session behavior (the OAuth2 RFC says it's beyond its scope). But if the server supports user sessions, it probably does so to remember the user's identity and consents. So I think it's safe to assume that a general purpose server will behave the way you described in the last point. And if there was a `prompt` value forcing such a behavior, the specification would start requiring a concrete server behavior, which could be in conflict with server settings or rules. That would make the spec less flexible.